# Assigning toolbar to the certain perspectives eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I would like to show my own toolbar only when some special perspectives are shown. Here is my perspectives in plugin.xml:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectives">
      <perspective
            class="ui.StandViewPerspective"
            fixed="false"
            id="standViewPerspective"
            name="%perspective.name">
      </perspective>
      
      <perspective
            class="ui.StandDisPerspective"
            fixed="false"
            id="standDisPerspective"
            name="%perspective.name.0">
      </perspective>
   </extension>
```

and here is my toolbar:

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar
               id="ui.standToolbar">
               
            <command
                  commandId="ui.lowerdelay"
                  disabledIcon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui/icons/full/elcl16/collapseall.png"
                  icon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui/icons/full/elcl16/collapseall.png"
                  id="ui.toolbar.decrease"
                  label="%command.decrease.delay"
                  style="push">
            </command>
            
            <command
                  commandId="ui.upperdelay"
                  disabledIcon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui/icons/full/elcl16/expandall.png"
                  icon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.ui/icons/full/elcl16/expandall.png"
                  id="ui.toolbar.increase"
                  label="%command.increase.delay"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

but I didn't find any way how to show this toolbar only for these two perspectives. I had read [this article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html), but didn't find here anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is this solution is correct, but I have managed to solve my problem. To your comand you have to add:

```
<visibleWhen>
<with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
<equals value="perspective_id"/>
</with>
</visibleWhen>
```

final solution:

```
<command
commandId="ui.openDebug"                disabledIcon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.debug.ui/icons/full/obj16/rundebug.png"                icon="platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.debug.ui/icons/full/obj16/rundebug.png"
id="ui.toolbar.opendbg"
label="%command.open.debug"
style="push">
                  
<visibleWhen>
<with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
<equals value="ui.standViewPerspective"/>
</with>
</visibleWhen>
</command>
```

maybe it will help someone else :D You only here won't handle two or more perpectives with your toolbar.